# GeoDjango error: Only numeric values of degree units are allowed on geographic DWithin queries

Tags: error, geodjango

I'm trying to get N points within 5000 meters of a certain point. My database is Postgres(PostGIS). I have a model like this:

```
class Theatre(models.Model):
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Then I ran a couple lines in Django shell:

```
Theatre.objects.filter(geom__dwithin=(GEOSGeometry('POINT(30.111199 -97.309990)'), D(m=5000)))
```

and I get the error:

```
ValueError: Only numeric values of degree units are allowed on geographic DWithin queries.
```

I found the documentation in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries) and it discusses calculating the geometry distance. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. I've taken a stab at an answer below but in case it doesn't help, you could try to clean up and clarify the wording of your question so someone else who knows GeoDjango might be willing/able to. Use the "edit" button above this comment.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know GeoDjango, but, from a PostGIS PoV, there seems to be at least two potential problems:

1. If the arguments for `POINT()` should be longitude & latitude, they should probably be reversed: `(-97.3, 30.1)`.
2. `geom_dwithin` expects the distance to be in the same units as the geometry's SRS, which in your example (`srid=4326`) is degrees, not meters.

Study the GeoDjango or PostGIS documentation, or at least the various other questions on this site that involve ST_Dwithin(). Try Googling

```
site:gis.stackexchange.com st_dwithin
```

Comment: In my case, the same error was caused by 2, using miles instead of degrees.

Comment: @Justas How did you calculate degrees equivalent of "miles" or any other `Distance`?

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#std:fieldlookup-dwithin) and by the error message, you need to convert `D(m=5000)` to **degree units**. The following function can help you with that.

```py
import math

def distance_to_decimal_degrees(distance, latitude):
    """
    Source of formulae information:
        1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees
        2. http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
    :param distance: an instance of `from django.contrib.gis.measure.Distance`
    :param latitude: y - coordinate of a point/location
    """
    lat_radians = latitude * (math.pi / 180)
    # 1 longitudinal degree at the equator equal 111,319.5m equiv to 111.32km
    return distance.m / (111_319.5 * math.cos(lat_radians))
```

After which you can then call your query as follows:

```py
Theatre.objects.filter(geom__dwithin=(GEOSGeometry('POINT(30.111199 -97.309990)'), distance_to_decimal_degrees(D(m=5000), -97.309990)))
```

Comment: I have used this approach, for me, the filtered data gives more output than expected. For eg. the distance between the point and the output sounds more than provided distance in google map. Please advice me on it.

Comment: I have one more question. While we need latitude and longitude to define a geographic point, how can we measure the distance only with the influence of latitude.