# Getting Output out of the scope-Geo Django

Tags: geodjango

I have a location and I want all the properties around within 100 km  to the location. I tried to follow this([GeoDjango error: Only numeric values of degree units are allowed on geographic DWithin queries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94645/geodjango-error-only-numeric-values-of-degree-units-are-allowed-on-geographic-d?newreg=b6399192baa0442ab5a9ee54be2376a3)). However, once I get the output and check the actual distance between the property and location its more than 100 km as of 195km, 209 km etc. Could someone advice me why. I followed exactly same code as bellow.

```
import math

def distance_to_decimal_degrees(distance, latitude):
    """
    Source of formulae information:
        1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees
        2. http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
    :param distance: an instance of `from django.contrib.gis.measure.Distance`
    :param latitude: y - coordinate of a point/location
    """
    lat_radians = latitude * (math.pi / 180)
    # 1 longitudinal degree at the equator equal 111,319.5m equiv to 111.32km
    return distance.m / (111_319.5 * math.cos(lat_radians))

#After which you can then call your query as follows:
Theatre.objects.filter(geom__dwithin=(GEOSGeometry('POINT(30.111199 -97.309990)'), distance_to_decimal_degrees(D(m=5000), -97.309990)))
```

I have one more question. While we need latitude and longitude to define a geographic point, how can we measure the distance only with the influence of latitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is..

```
 import math

def distance_to_decimal_degrees(distance, latitude):
    return distance.m / 111_319.5 

#After which you can then call your query as follows:
Theatre.objects.filter(geom__dwithin=(GEOSGeometry('POINT(30.111199 -97.309990)'), distance_to_decimal_degrees(D(m=5000)))
```

Th way I have calculated this digit( 111_319.5) as if I take one point in the targeted radius I can get an arc with the interested location. That arc can be completed as a circle with the center of globe and radius of globe. the required degree here is the degree mapped by the arc in the center of the globe.
That can be calculated as follows

```
(distance* 360) / (2 * math.pi * radius of globe)
```